# Programmatically show suggestions for react-autosuggest

Tags: reactjs, autosuggest

I am using the react-autosuggest library here: https://react-autosuggest.js.org/  Now I have the list of input suggestions pop up below the input box when the user clicks in the input box, similar to a dropdown list.  But I have also added a font-awesome down arrow inside the input box.  When that is clicked, nothing happens.  I just want it to show the list same focusing the actual input box.

Here is how I am rendering the input component:

```js
    const renderInputComponent = (inputProps) => (
        <div className="inputContainer">
            {selectedCustomer ? (
                <FontAwesomeIcon
                    icon={faTimes}
                    size={'1x'}
                    onClick={() => {
                        setSelectedCustomer('');
                        setSuggestionValue('');
                    }}
                />
            ) : (
                <FontAwesomeIcon
                    icon={faAngleDown}
                    size={'1x'}
                    onClick={() => {
                      ??? <-- this is where I think I would put something to show those suggestions
                    }}
                />
            )}
            {/*<input {...inputProps} ref={autosuggestInput} />*/}
            <input {...inputProps} />
            {/* when I add in the above commented to code to show options when the caret is clicked, I get an error: https://github.com/moroshko/react-autosuggest/pull/631 */}
        </div>
    );
```

I have created a Code Sandbox demonstrating my request.  I added the comment where I think the code should go.
https://codesandbox.io/s/compassionate-ramanujan-yi9i8?file=/src/App.js

And here is an image:

[image]

That dropdown caret icon should show all the results the same as clicking in the box does:

[image]

Comment: would you able to provide the expected output image, and codesandbox to understand your problem better.

Comment: I added a Code Sandbox at the bottom.

Comment: Added images as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can trigger the dropdown by focusing in on the input. To do this, just create a ref to it:

```
const autosuggestInput = useRef(null);

...

<input {...inputProps} ref={autosuggestInput} />
```

And when the dropdown icon is clicked, call `setFocus()` on the element

```
<FontAwesomeIcon
  icon={faAngleDown}
  size={"1x"}
  onClick={() => {
    autosuggestInput.current.focus();
  }}
/>
```

You can find a forked repo where this is fixed here: https://codesandbox.io/s/confident-bash-bu789?file=/src/App.js:2875-3047

Comment: Thank you!  I thought I had tried that before and gotten an error, but it works now!